# Does anyone know how to change from AutoIT code to Java?

Tags: java, autoit

I have the following AutoIT code and I'd like to know how to migrate/translate to Java

AutoIT:

```
   AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode","20")
   WinWait("Authentication Required")
   While WinExists("Authentication Required")
      Opt("SendKeyDelay", 50)
      $title = WinGetTitle("Authentication Required") ; retrieves whole window title
      $UN=WinGetText($title,"User Name:")
      ControlSend($title,"",$UN,"myemail@gmail.com{TAB}");Sets Username and {TAB}
      $PWD=WinGetText($title,"Password:")
      ControlSend($title,"",$PWD,"mypassword");Sets PWD  and {ENTER}
      ControlSend($title,"",$PWD,"{ENTER}");
      Sleep(2000)
   WEnd
   Exit
```

This is what I tried to convert to Java:

```
public void shouldEnterCredentials() throws Throwable {
        try {
            File file = new File("lib", "jacob-1.18-x64.dll"); //path to the jacob dll
            System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

            AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
            String title = x.winGetTitle("Authentication Required");
            String un = x.winGetText(title,"User Name:");
            String pwd = x.winGetText(title,"Password:");

            x.autoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode","20");
            x.winWait("Authentication Required");
            while (x.winExists("Authentication Required")){
               x.autoItSetOption("OPT_SEND_KEY_DELAY", "50");
               x.controlSend(title,"", un, "myemail@gmail.com{TAB}"); //Sets Username and {TAB}
               x.controlSend(title,"",pwd,"mypassword"); //Sets PWD  and {ENTER}
               x.controlSend(title, "", pwd,"{ENTER}");
               x.sleep(2000);
            }       

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Why doesn't your code work? Please include your error message. As written, some people might think you're asking SO to be a coding service for you.

Comment: So, whats is the error? What happened? Or not Happened?

Comment: Hey guys, currently is not being executed, so nothing happens, maybe something is wrong on my java code

Answer (score 2):

Why not compile the AutoIt code and run it from your Java code?

Your AutoIt code is not returning anything so it is easier (and more reliable) to compile your AutoIt script and simply execute the batch file from there.